# How can I write a maximum likelihood routine in R?

Tags: r

I want to run some maximum likelihood code on the data sample I have created. This is what I have so far:

```
library("maxLik") 
data <- replicate(20, rnorm(100))
logLikFun <- function(param) {
mu <- param[1]
sigma <- param[2]
sum(dnorm(data, mean = mu, sd = sigma, log = TRUE))
}
mle <- maxLik(logLik = logLikFun, start = c(mu = 0, sigma = 1))
summary(mle)
```

I am having some problems extracting the mean and standard deviation for each sample of the 20, I amended the apply function to try to suit this but nothing has worked yet. Any ideas?

Comment: Exactly what "problems"? Did you get an error message or was the answer not what you expected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a function (`find.mle` in this example) that takes a vector of data and calculates the MLE based on it, and then use `apply` to apply that to the columns of `data`:

```
library("maxLik") 
data <- replicate(20, rnorm(100))

find.mle = function(d) {
    logLikFun <- function(param) {
        mu <- param[1]
        sigma <- param[2]
        sum(dnorm(d, mean = mu, sd = sigma, log = TRUE))
    }
    maxLik(logLik = logLikFun, start = c(mu = 0, sigma = 1))$estimate
}

mles = apply(data, 2, find.mle)
```

This will give you a 2x20 matrix with your estimates:

```
> mles
            [,1]      [,2]        [,3]       [,4]       [,5]        [,6]
mu    0.03675611 0.1129927 -0.06499549 0.04651673 0.06593217 -0.08753828
sigma 0.93497523 0.9817961  0.84734600 0.93139761 1.01083924  1.04114752
           [,7]       [,8]      [,9]       [,10]      [,11]       [,12]
mu    0.1629807 0.01665411 0.2306688 -0.02147982 0.07723695 0.009476477
sigma 1.0428713 1.01658241 1.0073277  0.99781761 0.99327722 0.983356049
           [,13]      [,14]      [,15]      [,16]     [,17]     [,18]
mu    0.06524147 0.02442983 -0.1305258 -0.1050299 0.1449996 0.1172218
sigma 1.04004799 0.89963009  0.9979824  1.0227063 0.9319562 0.9916734
           [,19]       [,20]
mu    -0.1288296 -0.05769467
sigma  0.9975368  0.89506586
```

Comment: thanks for that, i am actually looking for the mu and sigma for all 20 samples. the summary(mle) already gives me the overall mu and sigma but i want it disaggregated for each of hte 20 different samples. Thanks

Comment: Ah! In that case, my edited answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: very nice, i had just discovered a couple of these terms and was working towards this but would have taken me a lot longer. Interestingly when i call mle.estimates, R is telling me it cant be found.

Comment: Sorry- I meant to put `mles` (the name of the variable I'd created in the previous code, I had changed it mid posting)

Comment: yeah i figured it out eventually, thanks. Is there any easy way to convert the mles output to just two columns with twenty rows? 20x2 rather than 2x20 matrix

Comment: `t(mles)` (the `t` function transposes the matrix)

Comment: thanks, you were a big help. i am finally seeking to extract the sd of mu for the twenty samples to achieve the sample error. typically i would have used stderr <-sd(Stats[,1]) but as i have another piece of code with that in there already i need something different. Any suggestions as simple alterations arent working for me right now. Thanks

Comment: "as i have another piece of code with that in there already i need something different"... I have no idea what you mean by this.

Comment: ok ignore that, i require the standard error for the mean of the 20 samples

Comment: Assuming that `Stats = t(mles)`, why not just `sd(Stats[, 1])`?

Answer (score 1):

I really think that there is not need to write any function in order to obtain the maximum likelihood (ML hereafter) estimators for the mean and sd. If X is a normal random variable then the ML estimators for the population mean and sd are the sample mean and the sample sd, and we know that the sample mean is an unbiased estimator for the population mean but the ML estimator for the variance is biased (downward), since the denominator for the variance is n instead of being n-1.

So R calculates the sample quasi-variance (corrected for the degrees of freedom) and this is the unbiased estimator, so it is not the ML estimator, but we can obtain the ML estimator from the R estimation, simply we only have to multiply it by (n-1)*(1/n) and the result will be the ML estimation of the variance, then apply squared root and voilá you'll have the ML estimation for the sd, but I like easy stuff so, just multiply the sd by (n-1)*(1/n) and this is your answer. For a detailed explanation see Population variance and sample variance on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance

Now you can just simply do in R the following:

```
## Reproducing @ David Robinson code
install.packages('maxLik')
library("maxLik") 
set.seed(007)  ## making it reproducible
data <- replicate(20, rnorm(100))

find.mle = function(d) {
  logLikFun <- function(param) {
    mu <- param[1]
    sigma <- param[2]
    sum(dnorm(d, mean = mu, sd = sigma, log = TRUE))
  }
  maxLik(logLik = logLikFun, start = c(mu = 0, sigma = 1))$estimate
}

mles = apply(data, 2, find.mle)
apply(data, 2, function(x) c(Mean=mean(x), SD=(n-1)*(1/n)*sd(x))) # my simple answer.

# Comparing results:
> mles
           [,1]      [,2]        [,3]        [,4]       [,5]         [,6]        [,7]
mu    0.1386966 0.1304418 -0.03515036 -0.05065659 0.04170382 0.0007424064 -0.07625412
sigma 0.9540009 0.9442371  1.07218240  1.03162817 0.96140925 1.0274500157  0.87450358
            [,8]       [,9]      [,10]      [,11]      [,12]       [,13]       [,14]
mu    0.02024026 -0.1732926 0.03401213 -0.1254751 0.05263887 -0.01258275 -0.02843866
sigma 0.98456202  0.9628233 0.95087131  0.9912367 1.01347266  0.99542339  1.03761674
           [,15]       [,16]     [,17]      [,18]       [,19]    [,20]
mu    0.02441331 -0.03021781 0.2170172 0.02271656 -0.04946737 0.115728
sigma 1.03889635  1.02796932 1.0457951 1.07906578  0.93627993 1.009641

>  apply(data, 2, function(x) c(Mean=mean(x), SD=(n-1)*(1/n)*sd(x)))
          [,1]      [,2]        [,3]        [,4]       [,5]         [,6]        [,7]
Mean 0.1386966 0.1304418 -0.03515036 -0.05065659 0.04170382 0.0007424064 -0.07625412
SD   0.9492189 0.9395041  1.06680802  1.02645707 0.95659012 1.0222998579  0.87012008
           [,8]       [,9]      [,10]      [,11]      [,12]       [,13]       [,14]
Mean 0.02024026 -0.1732926 0.03401213 -0.1254751 0.05263887 -0.01258275 -0.02843866
SD   0.97962684  0.9579971 0.94610501  0.9862680 1.00839257  0.99043377  1.03241563
          [,15]       [,16]     [,17]      [,18]       [,19]    [,20]
Mean 0.02441331 -0.03021781 0.2170172 0.02271656 -0.04946737 0.115728
SD   1.03368881  1.02281656 1.0405530 1.07365689  0.93158677 1.004580
```

So you can delete the function (a very nice function written by @David Robinson) if you just use a simple product. This is a simple theoretical statistical point of view.